# One UINavigationcontroller for the whole app?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i´ve created a UINavigationController in my appdelegate and initialized it with my "modelselectionViewController". This VC has different uibuttons and when touched, a new VC ("modelViewController") is pushed on the navigationstack.

This "modelViewController" acts as my template view and has a uitabbarcontroller with different tabs. The first VC is shown immediately  but any changes on the navigationcontroller doesn´t work. I would like to set the name of the title but that navigationcontroller is null.

> NSLog(@"navi: %@",
>   self.navigationController);

If i change my code to push the different VC when touching the different tabs, navigation works but only with a third level of navigation hierachy.

I want to know if it´s possible to use only one navigationcontroller for all my different tabs. Hope i made my setup clear. Appreciate all your help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a UITabBarController from a view that's managed in a UINavigationController (ie: if you create a navigationcontroller first, and it's still around when you create the tabbarcontroller), you're starting a fight with the frameworks. Here's the admonishment from the docs on combining viewcontroller interfaces:

> An application that uses a tab bar
>   controller can also use navigation
>   controllers in one or more tabs. When
>   combining these two types of view
>   controller in the same user interface,
>   the tab bar controller always acts as
>   the wrapper for the navigation
>   controllers. You never want to push a
>   tab bar controller onto the navigation
>   stack of a navigation controller.
>   Doing so creates an unusual situation
>   whereby the tab bar appears only while
>   a specific view controller is at the
>   top of the navigation stack. Tab bars
>   are designed to be persistent, and so
>   this transient approach can be
>   confusing to users.

I read that as "if it doesn't break something that we haven't thought of on the next update, we might reject the app anyway because it's 'confusing to users.'"

I suppose you could kill the whole navigation hierarchy and the navigationcontroller if you don't need to return there (like if you just used it for a one-time setup screen). Or you can look into other options for navigating within a viewcontroller that's managed by the navigationcontroller.

One thing to try might be to navigate to a UITableView, and use its cells to push a modal view onto the navigation stack. That would be familiar to users and also jive with the intent of the navigation classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to read [Combining ViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1).

In general, you should have the tabbar controller as a 'root' controller, not as a 'child' controller. A quick search in Apple's doc didn't yield a formal 'forbidden', but it might be.